# Two .each function not working inside a function.

Tags: jquery

I have two div outside wrapper div. But I want to push both div inside wrapper.
Here is my code

```
<div class="eg-section-separetor"></div>
<div class="eg-parallax-scene"></div>
<div class="eg-section-separetor-wrapper eg-section-parallax"></div>

function pushInsideSection(){
  "use strict";
  jQuery(".eg-section-separetor").each(function(){
    try{
      var elem=jQuery(this).next(".eg-section-separetor-wrapper")[0];
      jQuery(this).prependTo(elem);   
    }catch(e){
    }
  });
  jQuery(".eg-parallax-scene").each(function(){
    try{
      var elem=jQuery(this).next(".eg-section-parallax")[0];
      jQuery(this).prependTo(elem);  
    }catch(e){
    }
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    pushInsideSection();
});
```

Problem is jQuery push second div which have class "eg-parallax-scene",but not pushing first div which have class "eg-section-separetor".

Any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `.next()` worked for immediate next element. while `eg-section-separetor-wrapper` is not immediate element after `eg-section-separetor`

So use [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
var elem=jQuery(this).siblings(".eg-section-separetor-wrapper")[0];
```

Or use `.next()` 2 times:-

```
var elem=jQuery(this).next().next(".eg-section-separetor-wrapper")[0];
```

Comment: @AlexRozario  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append` to put elements inside of another.

```js
function pushInsideSection() {
  var wrapper = $('.eg-section-separetor-wrapper');
  var sep = $('.eg-section-separetor');
  var scene = $('.eg-parallax-scene');
  wrapper.append(sep, scene);
}



$('#nest').click(function($) {
  pushInsideSection();
});

// To run on page load:
//$(function() {  
//  pushInsideSection();
//});
```

```css
.eg-section-separetor-wrapper {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.eg-section-separetor {
  background: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.eg-parallax-scene {
  background: white;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="eg-parallax-scene">this is the scene</div>
<div class="eg-section-separetor">This is the separator. it's ok if its in the wrong order in html. </br>You can append them in any order you want.</div>
<div class="eg-section-separetor-wrapper eg-section-parallax">
</div>
<button id="nest">click me to nest the divs</button>
```